# JS: How to solve this [object Promise]?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I got this problem [object Promise], when I am trying to load quotes from a API from this file https://type.fit/api/quotes. At the top of the page, after the loader finish, the quotes should be loaded, which are defined on the page https://type.fit/api/quotes . I am using async await function for this. I have next function: selectAndReturnRandomQuote, this function call loadQuotesFromJSON, which actually do fetch on link and return quotes, at the end of function I return print on page like this "Quote of the day: " + quote.quoteOfAuthor + " by " + quote.author. Next I have uploadQuote, which acutually with innerHTML put my result on page. Function sleep and setLoader are used to make loading quote, before acutally its shown.  Below are my code snippet.

```js
"use strict";


async function selectAndReturnRandomQuote() {
    let quotesFromJSON = await loadQuotesFromJSON();
    let quote = quotesFromJSON[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesFromJSON.length)];

    let result = "Quote of the day: " + quote.text+ " by " + quote.author;
    return result;
    
}

function uploadQuote(){
    document.getElementById('randomeQuotes').innerHTML = selectAndReturnRandomQuote();
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
 }
  
async function setLoader() {
    document.getElementById('randomeQuotes').innerHTML = "<img src='loader2.gif' width='28px' height='55px'>";
    await sleep(1000);  
    await uploadQuote();
}
  
setLoader();

async function loadQuotesFromJSON() {
    const response = await fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes');
    return response.json();
}
```

```css
div {
    white-space: pre-line;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    background-color:aliceblue;
    border-radius: 14px;
    opacity:0.83;
    width: 430px;
    position:relative;
    left: 80px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2.2px;
    border-color:aquamarine;
}

img {
    width: 100px; 
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2.2px;
    border-color:aquamarine;
}

body {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 55px;

    background-color:cadetblue;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Contact form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="FormExternalStyles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'randomeQuotes' class = "marginbottom">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
"use strict";


async function selectAndReturnRandomQuote() {
    let quotesFromJSON = await loadQuotesFromJSON();
    let quote = quotesFromJSON[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesFromJSON.length)];

    let result = "Quote of the day: " + quote.text+ " by " + quote.author;
    return result;
    
}

async function uploadQuote(){
    document.getElementById('randomeQuotes').innerHTML = await selectAndReturnRandomQuote();
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
 }
  
async function setLoader() {
    document.getElementById('randomeQuotes').innerHTML = "<img src='loader2.gif' width='28px' height='55px'>";
    await sleep(1000);  
    await uploadQuote();
}
  
setLoader();

async function loadQuotesFromJSON() {
    const response = await fetch('https://type.fit/api/quotes');
    return response.json();
}
```

```css
div {
    white-space: pre-line;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    background-color:aliceblue;
    border-radius: 14px;
    opacity:0.83;
    width: 430px;
    position:relative;
    left: 80px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2.2px;
    border-color:aquamarine;
}

img {
    width: 100px; 
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2.2px;
    border-color:aquamarine;
}

body {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 55px;

    background-image: url(pozadinalogin.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 530x 510px;
    background-color:cadetblue;
    background-position: 80px 90px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Contact form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="FormExternalStyles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'randomeQuotes' class = "marginbottom">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You forgot to set async and await for the uploadQuote function.

```
async function uploadQuote(){
    document.getElementById('randomeQuotes').innerHTML = await selectAndReturnRandomQuote();
}
```